# var _ = require('underscore') throws "Object expected" in Windows Scripting Host

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm going through a refresher on JS, and there is one exercise with the **Underscore** library:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
function print(n){
    console.log(n);
}

_.each([1,2,3],print);
```

Seems straightforward: I've installed the library via `npm install underscore`, my `package.lock.json` shows

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": {
      "version": "1.9.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.9.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-5/4etnCkd9c8gwgowi5/om/mYO5ajCaOgdzj/oW+0eQV9WxKBDZw5+ycmKmeaTXjInS/W0BzpGLo2xR2aBwZdg=="
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running node v10.9.0, npm v6.2.0. The **node_modules** folder exists.

I've tried using `import _ from 'underscore'` and `import {each } from 'underscore'`, too, but (expectedly) get the same error.

**Edit:** I'm a step further... if I install **Underscore** globally, the script runs fine. Can anyone figure out if there is an error in the package.lock.json that would cause it to not find the library, perhaps?

Comment: Windows Scripting Host sounds like the problem, how are you trying to run the JS? (Javascript !== JScript)

Comment: just in a test.js file via node (`node .\test.js`)

Comment: did you run npm install where you are running it?

Comment: yes, and the **node_modules** folder is there, along with the **underscore** files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with **Node. js** on this computer. I tried the example on another computer and it worked. So, I re-installed **Underscore.js** with no success (other than running it globally). Tested a few other libraries and ran into the same issue. Checked paths, permissions, all were OK. Reinstalled **Node.js**, and it just worked.